# Animate a window, sliding from right to left or from bottom to top

Tags: c#, animation

I am trying to implement an animation for a window such that it acts as sliding from the right to the left or from the bottom to the top.
I've tried the DoubleAnimation, which works for the case from the left to the right or from the top to the bottom.
Here is what I've tried:

```
myWindow.Show();
DoubleAnimation myAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
myAnimation.From = 0;
myAnimation.To = myWindow.ActualWidth;
myAnimation.SpeedRatio = 5;
myWindow.BeginAnimation(System.Windows.Window.WidthProperty, myAnimation);
```

If I replace `myWindow.ActualWidth` with `myWindow.ActualHeight`, and replace `WidthProperty` with `HeightProperty`, I will get the animation slides from top to bottom.

Do you know any similar and simple way to animate the window but slide from the right to the left? `myWindow.Left` and `myWindow.Top` have already been set.
Thank you so much for your help in advance. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Just revert the from and to values:

```
myAnimation.From = myWindow.ActualWidth;
myAnimation.To = 0;
```

Seems pretty obvious...

**Edit:**

You're animating the wrong property, try this:

```
myWindow.BeginAnimation(System.Windows.Window.LeftProperty, myAnimation);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, I am sorry , it's not like this. I am expecting from right to left but the final width is myWindow.ActualWidth instead of 0. I've tried this before posting the question. But the result is not what I want. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks @HighCore. I may not make myself clear enough. Actually, myWindow in the codes is a child window of a window named myOwnerWindow. I need to set the myWindow.Left = myOwnerWindow.Left + someValue. The someValue is set by other users. I've tried different myAnimation.From and myAnimation.To, however, none of them was what I am expecting. It's working the first time I opened the child window. However, the second time I opened it, it's been out of nowhere. Is it possible that I haven't close the animation? Do I need to check the animation is null or not every time?

Comment: @payson post your full code and please be specific to state your current issue.